# ¿Cómo acomodar las imágenes en forma de tabla con CSS?

Tags: html, css

Quiero acomodar las imagenes en forma de cuadro 3x3, *tres imagenes arriba y tres imagenes abajo*.

Estuve intentando varias cosas en el CSS pero me parece que el error está en el HTML y no logro darme cuenta dónde está el error. Adjunto imágenes de mi código. Las imágenes se me ven una arriba de la otra y se ven en tamaño gigante, es un desastre. Dejo una foto de como se ve la página ahora, es el principio, el resto de las imágenes gigantes continúan abajo.

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
article {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 75rem
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
ul  {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul .li  {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 1s;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class = "no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>MyPortfolio</title>
  <meta name ="author" content="">
  <meta name ="keywords" content="">
  <meta name ="description" content="">
  <link rel = "shortcut icon" type="imagenes/x-icon" href="img/favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="js/prefixfree.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1> DEVELOPER </h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h2> Cursos </h2>
      <article>
        <h3> 2020 </h3>
        <ul>
              </li><a href="imagen 1"><img src = "imagenes/imagen 1.png" alt = "imagen 1" class = "img"></a></li>

              </li><a href="imagen 2"><img src = "imagenes/imagen 2.png" alt = "imagen 2" class = "img"></a></li>
            

              <li><a href="imagen 3"><img src = "imagenes/imagen 3.jpg" alt = "imagen 3" class = "img"></a></li>
             

              <li><a href="imagen 4"><img src = "imagenes/imagen 4.png" alt = "imagen 4" class = "img"></a></li>
             

              <li><a href="imagen 5"><img src = "imagenes/imagen 5.jpg" alt = "imagen 5" class = "img"></a></li>
             
              <li><a href="imagen 6"><img src = "imagenes/imagen 6.png" alt = "imagen 6" class = "img"></a></li>
              
             
        </div>
        </ul>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto por favor, además ayudaría mucho que nos expliques que resultado obtienes con ese código en este momento?

Comment: Hola @BetaM ! ahí edite la publicacion

Comment: Tienes un HTML malformado, comienzas con `</li>`, espero que sea error de tecleo al crear el ejemplo. Te sugiero intentar con [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox), que es muy sencillo de usar.

Comment: si de todas las modificaciones que hice habré toqueteado mal. Recien lo arreglé y sigue viendose todo igual

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos si tratas de formar una cuadrícula te puedes auxiliar de [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) para definir el número de columnas y filas que deseas tenga tu composición.

Será mas simple y así se estaría evitando cambiar la naturaleza de bloque a línea a los elementos, así como el posicionamiento de estos.

Considera para este ejemplo:

- A la etiqueta contenedor de nuestra galería de imágenes le damos una disposición de tipo `grid` para que sus elementos internos se comporten en forma de rejilla
- La propiedad `grid-template-columns` nos permite definir el número y medida de las columnas que deseamos
- La propiedad `grid-auto-rows` nos facilita indicar la medida que cada fila debería tener en conjunto o indicando separados por un espacio la medida que deseamos en cada fila

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .galeria {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: 300px;
      }
      .galeria-imagen {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
    </style>
    <section class="galeria">
      <article class="galeria-imagen">Imagen 1</article>
      <article class="galeria-imagen">Imagen 2</article>
      <article class="galeria-imagen">Imagen 3</article>
      <article class="galeria-imagen">Imagen 4</article>
      <article class="galeria-imagen">Imagen 5</article>
      <article class="galeria-imagen">Imagen 6</article>
    </section>
    <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores odio corrupti suscipit doloremque, recusandae odit asperiores enim totam. Eos consequuntur inventore neque sit nihil esse iste reiciendis ab sunt quidem.
    </p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ahora lo voy a probar